# Asp.Net partial view doesn't reload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have got a view and inside this view I nested a partial view.
What I want to achieve is to reload the partial view from the main view via jQuery.

This is what I have got so far:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{Html.RenderAction("SkillResult", "Home"); }

<script type="text/javascript">

        var postData = { values: stringArray };

        // Fire off the request to controller
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '/Home/SkillResult',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: postData
        });
</script>
```

**SkillResult Controller (Partial view)**

```
public ActionResult SkillResult(List<String> values)
{
        SkillContext skillContext = new SkillContext();
        List<Skill> result= skillContext.Skills.ToList();

        return PartialView(result);
}
```

**SkillResult.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Result>
@using SkillSearch.Models

<h2>SkillResult</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Name
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

As you can see I fire the Ajax request from the Index.cshtml where the partial view is inside. If I debug I can see that all the requests are working but the partial view is not updating its content.

Comment: You will need to `JSON.stringify(postData)` your data! :-)

Comment: It arrives in the controller successfully without doing that

Comment: What is `values` in your controller?

Comment: The data it receives from the ajax call

Comment: This isn't being passed into your result partial

Comment: LOL he means what does it contain.... It is not clear from your code why you are expecting it to update atall... You render the view, then immediately do an ajax call with no success handler. What makes you think this will do it? Add a success handler to your ajax call

Comment: I shortened the code. The code is way too long.

Comment: Yes it is passed into the controller. @MattWebb

Comment: You are not dealing with the action result on your jquery call. You have to get the data and manually update your page (checkout the success parameter of jQuery's ajax function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you haven't specified success handler in your ajax call

I have modified your code little bit to demonstrate how it works

Hope it will help :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var postData = { values: stringArray };

    // Fire off the request to controller
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/SkillResult',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: postData,
        success:function(result){
            $(element).html(result);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but somehow it doesn't jump into the success function.

Comment: check console or use ajax error handler so you can track error

Comment: Got it. I had to change dataType to HTML instead of Json. Change that in your answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: changed it to html :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks:)